# LibGdx Smooth background color change

Tags: java, libgdx

I am developing a game on Libgdx. The background on my game is just Gl.clear color. I want to SMOOTHLY change background if the score is bigger than 5. So how can I do it with Gl.clearColor. Or I need to try something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either look at [ColorAction](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/ColorAction.java) for inspiration, or just use it directly:

```java
Color color = new Color(Color.WHITE);
ColorAction colorAction = new ColorAction();

public MyGame() {
    colorAction.setColor(color);
    colorAction.setDuration(2);
    colorAction.setEndColor(Color.RED);
}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    colorAction.act(delta);
}
```

When you want to change the background color, just use this:

```java
colorAction.reset();
colorAction.setEndColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: But how can i change color at runtime? I mean how to switch between 3 colors or more?

Comment: If you want to transition between colors then interact with the `colorAction` object like in the second code block above. Call `reset` followed by `setEndColor`.

Comment: This is not working, the original color does not change

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using interpolation. Should be self-explanatory.

```
private final Color clearColor = new Color();
private final Color startingClearColor = new Color();
private final Color targetClearColor = new Color();
private float elapsedClearColorChangeTime;
private float clearChangeDuration;

private void changeClearColor(int colorHex, float duration){ //for example 0xff0000ff for Red
    targetClearColor.set(colorHex);
    startingClearColor.set(clearColor);
    elapsedClearColorChangeTime = 0;
    clearChangeDuration = duration;
}

private void updateClearColor(float deltaTime){
    if (elapsedClearColorChangeTime < clearChangeDuration){
        elapsedClearColorChangeTime = Math.min(elapsedClearColorChangeTime + deltaTime, clearChangeDuration);
        clearColor.set(startingClearColor).lerp(targetClearColor, 
            Interpolation.fade.apply(elapsedClearColorChangeTime / clearChangeDuration));
    }
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a);
}

public void render(float deltaTime){
    updateClearColor(deltaTime);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Try the other answer first. It's simpler. Totally slipped my mind that you can use a ColorAction without needing a stage.